# How to read an object with a cycle(for)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I've been searching for how can I check all object's properties with a cycle(for) and didn't find very much.

I've been working in a register form validation with JS and jquery, I added an object with a property(`false` or `true`) for each field, just to know if a field is not filled correctly. I want to check all the properties looking for a `false` and if there is one, disable the button. I tried to read the object like this:

```
for(var p in flags){ // flags = object
            if(p == false){
                flagStatus = false;
            }
        }
        if(flagStatus )
            $("#subReg").attr("disabled", false);   
        else
            $("#subReg").attr("disabled", true);
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. Any help would be great, ty.

EDIT:

```
var flags = {nick: false, pass:false, passVer:false, genero:false, pais:false, fechaNac:false, nombre:false, apellido:false, email:false, checkBox:false, captcha:false};
```

Comment: Can you show what `flags` looks like? Your looping looks fine, but `p` refers to the key. Did you mean `if(flags[p] == false){`? That will get the value. Also, you might want to add `break;` inside the `if` statement to stop looping as soon as something matches.

Comment: At first glance that should work, what error are you getting?

Comment: Try `$("#subReg").prop("disabled", false); `

Comment: Actually isn't it `$("#subReg").css("disabled", false);`

Comment: @Nomad101 No, setting the `disabled` **property**, you want to use `.prop()`. If you were setting a style, you'd use `.css()`

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but still not working. Good idea for the break and "Nomad101" I guess both ways works

Comment: I thought you could set the property through css or am I thinking visibility?

Comment: @Nomad101 You're thinking visibility :) The things you set with `.css()` are the things you access in normal Javascript with `element.style.whatever`. Make sense?

Comment: Totally sorry for the mistake editing now.

Comment: I was getting the key and not the value. Fool me xD ... I hope anyone find useful this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get/compare the **value**, not the **key**. Try this:

```
var flags = {key1: true, key2: false, key3: true};
var flagStatus = true;
for (var p in flags){
    if (flags[p] === false) {
        flagStatus = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (flagStatus)
    $("#subReg").attr("disabled", false);   
else
    $("#subReg").attr("disabled", true);
```

When looping, the `p` refers to the **key** in the object, while `flags[p]` refers to the **value**.

In my example above, the first `p` encountered is "key1", and `flags[p]` is `true`. Next, `p` is "key2" and `flags[p]` is `false` - so the `if` statement passes, `flagStatus` is set to `false`, and the looping stops.

Also, you could combine the code at the end (after the loop) to be:

```
$("#subReg").attr("disabled", !flagStatus);
```

So you dont need the if/else :)

Comment: its a foreach loop? why would you need to use the indexer? Or is my understanding of a foreach loop in javascript mistaken?

Comment: Good call my friend, there was my problem, I was getting the key not the vale. thx

Comment: @Nomad101 that's not a foreach [i.e. an iterator over the values], it's an iterator over the keys.

Comment: hmmm I see, interesting ok well there you go learn something new every day.